# Ionic: ScreenOrientation to Portrait

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am developing an Ionic-App and I want to set the Screen Orientation to Portrait.
and I know I could set it with this:

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```

but this isn't working,

I found a cordova plugin called screen-orientation-plugin but this is not working too. Do you have any another solution for this? Or Can anyone explain me how these 2 methods are working correctly?

```
.config(function($ionicConfigProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $compileProvider) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {

      $scope.changeOriantationPortrait = function() {
          screen.lockOrientation('portrait');
      }
      changeOriantationPortrait();
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying the the orientation is set to landscape by default?

Comment: @MegaAppBear No, i mean i cant freeze the orientation to portrait

Comment: cordova version? OS where you tested?

Comment: cordova 5.3.3 and iOS 9

Answer (score 0):

I have used **[this](https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation)** plugin for my project and it is worked perfectly

```
cordova plugin add net.yoik.cordova.plugins.screenorientation
```

**Controller**

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    $scope.changeOriantationLandspace = function() {
        screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
    }

    $scope.changeOriantationPortrait = function() {
        screen.lockOrientation('portrait');
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="button button-full button-positive " ng-click="changeOriantationLandspace()">Change To Landspace Mode</button>
<br/>
<button class="button button-full button-positive " ng-click="changeOriantationPortrait ()">Change To Portrait Mode</button>
```

**[Reference](http://www.gajotres.net/changing-locking-screen-orientation-in-ionic-application/)**

Comment: Thank you Mushin, yeah i tried this too, but when i implement it into my code, the whole app doesnt work and in the console he says screen is not a function :/

Comment: the Problem is, that i am getting no error. The device Ready listener dont get fired, but when i commenting the methods out, the deviceready event gets fired.

Comment: added it in the question

Comment: Can You create a small demo for me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96579/discussion-between-muhsin-and-bernhard-miehl).

Comment: Please open this link http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96579/discussion-between-muhsin-and-bernhard-miehl

Comment: Or come to skype (Skype Id:muhsin.k9)